# What could be causing this non-crashing NRE?

Tags: c#, sqlite, compact-framework, windows-ce, nullreferenceexception

The problematic method, *PopulateTransactionListBoxWithWorkTables()*, gets called from the main form's Load event:

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog("Reached frmMain.frmMain_Load");
    ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new TrustAllCertificatesPolicy();
    PopulateTransactionListBoxWithWorkTables();
}
```

Somewhere in that method, it fails with an NRE; I've sprinkled in a bunch of log msgs to see just where it's failing:

```
private void PopulateTransactionListBoxWithWorkTables()
{
    ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog("Reached 
frmMain.PopulateTransactionListBoxWithWorkTable");
    menuItemSEND_Deliveries.Enabled = false;
    menuItemSEND_Inventories.Enabled = false;

    try
    {
        listBoxWork.Items.Clear();

        ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog("Reached 
frmMain.PopulateTransactionListBoxWithWorkTable#2");
        if (!hhsdbutils.TableExists("WorkTable"))
        {
            ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog("Reached 
frmMain.PopulateTransactionListBoxWithWorkTable#3a");
            String msg = HHSConsts.NO_CURRENT_WORK;
listBoxWork.Items.Add(msg);
        }
        else
        {
            ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog("Reached 
frmMain.PopulateTransactionListBoxWithWorkTable#3b");
            List<String> workTables = hhsdbutils.GetWorkTableNames();
menuItemTopSend.Enabled = workTables.Count > 0;

            foreach (String wt in workTables)
            {
                // TODO: This will cause enabled to be set to true each time a corresponding 
item is found, which should be improved
                if (wt.IndexOf("DSD") == 0)
                {
                    menuItemSEND_Deliveries.Enabled = true;
                }
                if (wt.IndexOf("INV") == 0)
                {
                    menuItemSEND_Inventories.Enabled = true;
                }
                listBoxWork.Items.Add(wt);
            }
            ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog("Reached 
frmMain.PopulateTransactionListBoxWithWorkTable#4");
            if (listBoxWork.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                listBoxWork.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       String msgInnerExAndStackTrace = String.Format(
     "{0}; Inner Ex: {1}; Stack Trace: {2}", ex.Message, ex.InnerException, ex.StackTrace);
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Exception in    
            PopulateTransactionListBoxWithWorkTable(): {0}", msgInnerExAndStackTrace));
       ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog(String.Format("From 
frmMain.PopulateTransactionListBoxWithWorkTable: {0}", msgInnerExAndStackTrace));
    }
} // populateListBoxWithWorkTableData
```

The log file shows that it gets to #2 in PopulateTransactionListBoxWithWorkTables(), but not to #3 (a or b) there:

```
Message: Reached frmMain.frmMain_Load

Date: 4/3/2009 2:13:28 AM
Message: Reached frmMain.PopulateTransactionListBoxWithWorkTable

Date: 4/3/2009 2:13:28 AM
Message: Reached frmMain.PopulateTransactionListBoxWithWorkTable#2

Date: 4/3/2009 2:13:31 AM
Message: Reached frmMain.frmMain_Activated

Date: 4/3/2009 2:13:31 AM
Message: From frmMain.PopulateTransactionListBoxWithWorkTable: NullReferenceException; Inner Ex: ; Stack Trace:    at HHS.frmMain.PopulateTransactionListBoxWithWorkTables()
   at HHS.frmMain.frmMain_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form._SetVisibleNotify(Boolean fVis)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Visible(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form fm)
   at HHS.Program.Main()
```

... so it's dying when calling TableExists(); here is that method:

```
bool IHHSDBUtils.TableExists(string tableName)
{
    ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog(String.Format("Reached 
SQliteHHSDBUtils.TableExists ({0})", tableName));
    // If the database file itself does not exist, there's no way the table could exist, so cut 
to the chase:
    if (!File.Exists(expectedSQLiteLocAndName)) return false;
    . . .
```

...the log msg at the start of TableExistsis not getting logged, so it seems to blow up as soon as it reaches it...why would that be the case?!?

**Note:** *frmMain_Activated()* has no code in it other than the log string write.

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints. In this case, clearly, `hhsdbutils` is null.

Comment: Also, why do you call this a "non-crashing NRE"? It would have crashed if you hadn't caught it.